# Python Strptime not returning a date, but returning entire text file

Tags: python, date, datetime, text-files, strptime

I'm trying to strip dates from a text file, but everything I have attempted so far returns the entire text file minus the newline and special characters.  I've stripped the text file down to a short paragraph for the purposes of checking my code.  The contents of the text file are as follows:

> 03/01/2018
>
> L205:
>
> On-site 7:00 AM, no crew on-site
>
> On-site 11:30 AM crew has excavated for the vessel pad and is watering
>   rock for placement and compaction. Excavation is measured out and
>   meets the requirements including overex on the plans. Off-site 12:00
>   PM.
>
> CBK-54:
>
> On-site 7:10 AM crew is installing RCP, crew has installed
>   approximately 80 feet from the manhole. Slurry arrives and the manhole
>   is slurried in place. Off-site 8:30 AM
>
> On-site 1:10 PM, crew has installed more RCP and is nearing
>   completion. Soil is holding up well. Off-site 1:40 PM

I'm wanting to strip the date "03/01/2018" from the text file which is named "Daily_Reports.txt" and is stored on my desktop.

The code I've tried so far is as follows:

```
import datetime

reports = open('C:/Users/onlyn_000/Desktop/Daily_Reports.txt').read()
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(reports, '%m/%d/%Y').date())
```

I'm really not even sure if this is a proper approach to my problem.  I would ultimately like to pull out each sentence/paragraph for each site (L205, CBK-54, etc.) to input into an excel spreadsheet, or even separate text file for each day.  I just want to get the date stripping down as a first step.  Any input would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

The answer to this question was given by mobone below.  The code that worked for me is as follows:

```
import datetime
import re

reports = open('C:/Users/onlyn_000/Desktop/Daily_Reports.txt').read()
dates = re.findall('[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9]*', reports)

for x in dates:
    print(datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y').date())
```

EDIT 2:

For future reader's reference.  I also realized that re.findall returns a list and the for loop I wrote only re-formats the dates into a datetime format.  I'm not even sure if I even need a datetime format for my application and I may just be able to use the list.

Comment: You are processing the entire file in one line.  What did you expect?

Comment: Which piece of text do you want to find the datetime for?

Comment: chrisz I wanted to find the datetime for the month, day, and year.  Stephen Rauch Frankly I expected it to strip out the datetime, but obviously that didn't work so I assume I have a misunderstanding of how strptime works and what the best approach would be.  My understanding was that it would strip out the dates for any given string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to look into `re.findall('[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9]*', reports)` to pull the date string out of the file. And then use strptime to parse it.

Comment: Your answer seems to be working so far. I don't understand why though.  For anyone who may find this thread the solution that worked was to do exactly as mobone has described.  This produces a list that can be iterated through to print off each date.  The code that worked will be edited into the original comment.

Comment: This uses a regular expression. a RE tries to match a given expression to the string provided. in this case, its two digits with a range of [0-9][0-9] followed by a slash, etc.

Comment: Check out regex101.com to try it out more interactively. Regular expressions are very powerful and have their own sort of syntax. You should spend some time to learn more about their syntax.

Comment: I've heard of regular expressions before.  I get the gist of what is going on in regards to the regular expressions, but I haven't spent nearly enough time using them to know as much as I should, which I believe is clear.  I guess my question more pertains to the reason why regular expressions must be used, and why datetime.strptime cannot be used.  I will also confess that I don't know much at all about the datetime library and module, other than it's what I've seen in answers to similar questions.  I suppose I should do some homework on that entire library as well.

Comment: Datetime.strptime takes a string, particularly a string that can be formatted as a datetime object and only that section of string. Datetime.strptime will not take a block of text and pull date times out of it. You only provide strptime the string that has the date in it and only the date in it. The format section of strptime must match exactly to the letters in the string.

Comment: You can use this to pull out the site names using this `[A-Z0-9-]*:\n` and then use reports.find(site_name) to find the start and end of the paragraph. let me know if you need help. I wouldn't mind writing this up for ya.